# What exactly is --no-daemon function in Gnome-power-manager

Tags: power-management, monitor, flicker

I have problem with monitor flickering and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal-info/+bug/415023) i found that possible solution is to run gnome-power-manager like this:

```
gnome-power-manager --no-daemon
```

For some people this fixed the issues. I am asking what exactly is this --no-daemon function and can it negatively affect the system? Put it other way: can i always run gnome-power-manager with --no-daemon function?

Thx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The description of the `--no-daemon` option from `man gnome-power-manager` is:

> --no-daemon
>
> > Do not detach gnome-power-manager into the background so that error messages will be displayed on console.

From this it looks like the option is merely preventing gnome-power-manager from forking output into a background process (e.g. it will write to the console rather than a log file or similar), so running with this option shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thx for answer. So if i run a command "gnome-power-manager --no-daemon & disown" how can i see error problems since i "disowned" the proccess.